# Optional limit for oracle queries

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, limit

Is it possible to make the `limit` clause in an Oracle query optional based on a parameter?

---

I've got some heavy queries that thake lots of time to execute so I'd like to fetch like only 10 rows during testing (which is nearly instant), but I don't want to use separate queries for each case.

Comment: Hi, for the testing purpose you can create Views with the Limit clause.

Comment: Consider adding sample data and expected output for debugging purposes.

Comment: This is not advisable, as the execution plan may change a lot between a SQL with limit and without (if by limit you mean the 'fetch first 10 rows').

Comment: If you do not care about any specific rows you may use `where rownum < 11 or param_value = <something>` to fetch 10 *arbitrary* rows (since where is evaluated before `order by`)

Comment: For testing throughput ad-hoc it's better to wrap your query with a `select COUNT(*) from ( [original query] )` so you don't include your client display in your timing. Even better, use an anonymous PL/SQL block with a cursor and loop through the results but do nothing inside the loop. That ensures all desired columns are projected. You can then also use timestamps to display exact timing. As for the limit idea, any imposed limit would skip any nested loops operations that fall on the outermost (last) steps of the plan for the other rows, hiding what's truly happening when there isn't a limit.

Comment: Where do these queries come from - an application or PL/SQL objects? The solution might depend on the context. For example, if the queries are generated by an application, maybe a SQL Macro could help. If the queries are in PL/SQL, then maybe conditional compilation could help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your context but you coould either define the parameter within FETCH FIRST &X ROWS ONLY and will be asked to enter the value or you could have it stored in a table and change it as you need.

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        ( Select LEVEL "ID", TRUNC(SYSDATE) - (LEVEL - 1) "DT" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 10 )

Select * 
From tbl
Fetch FIRST &X ROWS ONLY  -- for X = 3
--
--          ID DT       
--  ---------- ---------
--           1 05-JUN-23
--           2 04-JUN-23
--           3 03-JUN-23
--
Select * 
From tbl
Fetch FIRST (Select 5 From Dual) ROWS ONLY

--          ID DT       
--  ---------- ---------
--           1 05-JUN-23
--           2 04-JUN-23
--           3 03-JUN-23
--           4 02-JUN-23
--           5 01-JUN-23
```